# RUBY: Unable to install 0ci8 library on Ruby 2.1.5p273 (windows 8.1) and connect to Oralce

Tags: ruby, oracle, oci8

I am facing serious limitation and issue (I guess is OS related), i have looked into many Forums also in Ruby's one, but not really great help has come from them; i truly think that has not really a great support or API/libraries availability for the community.

DETAILS:

Ruby Version: 2.1.5p273

Ruby path: C:\Ruby21\bin

Gem version: 2.2.2

OS: Windows 8.1 64-bit

ORACLE version:  Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Oracle: D:\app\username\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1

in CMD

```
gem install ruby-oci8  --source http://rubygems.org
```

but many errors:

```
checking for load library path...
  PATH...
    checking D:\app\Usern\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin...   skip: D:/app/Usern/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/oci.dll is for x86_64 cpu.
    checking C:\app\Username\product\12.1.0\dbhome_3\bin... no
    checking C:\app\Username\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\bin... no
    checking C:\app\Username\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin... no
    checking C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\... no
    checking C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\... no
    checking C:\WINDOWS\system32... no
    checking C:\WINDOWS... no
    checking C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem... no
    checking C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\... no
    checking C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86... no
    checking C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64... no
    checking C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL... no
    checking C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT... no
    checking C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL... no
    checking C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT... no
    checking C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\... no
    checking C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\... no
    checking D:\Strawberry\c\bin... no
    checking D:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin... no
    checking D:\Strawberry\perl\bin... no
    checking C:\php... no
    checking C:\\bin... no
    checking C:\scala\bin... no
    checking C:\Ruby21\bin... no
    checking C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin... no
checking for cc... ---------------------------------------------------
Error Message:
  The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
  You have to install development tools first.

    Error Message:
      The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
      You have to install development tools first.

Backtrace:
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:840:in `try_run'
  C:/Ruby21/ruby-oci8-2.1.7/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:566:in `check_cc'
  C:/Ruby21/ruby-oci8-2.1.7/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:556:in `init'
  C:/Ruby21/ruby-oci8-2.1.7/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:705:in `initialize'
  C:/Ruby21/ruby-oci8-2.1.7/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `new'
  C:/Ruby21/ruby-oci8-2.1.7/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `get'
  C:/Ruby21/ruby-oci8-2.1.7/ext/oci8/extconf.rb:18:in `<main>'
---------------------------------------------------
See:
 * http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-full-client.md for Oracle full client
 * http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-instant-client.md for Oracle instant client
 * http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/file.report-installation-issue.html to report an issue.

*** C:/Ruby21/ruby-oci8-2.1.7/ext/oci8/extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Why i need this?

I am working with CSV files, arrays and Maps for a small exercise... but my solution will perfect using real DB tables and referential integrity... but i am afraid i will bever install oci8 in ruby:

i show one code example whihc is failing

```
require 'oci8'


#sqlplus fred/fred@localhost:1521/DB1


oci = OCI8.new('fred','fred','localhost:1521/DB1')
oci.exec('select sysdate from dual') do |record|
  puts record
end


ERROR in Eclipse Luna:

C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- oci8 (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Username/db.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: i also tried C:\Ruby21\ruby-oci8-2.1.7>gem install dbi--source http://rubygems.org
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'dbi--source' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'http://rubygems.org' (>= 0)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby-oci8 provides binary gems for Windows. But they are not available when `--source http://rubygems.org` is passed to `gem install ruby-oci8`.

Firstly, you need 64-bit ruby to use 64-bit Oracle.
Note that the latest ruby-oci8 binary gems (version 2.1.7) don't bundle extension libraries for ruby 2.2.1. You should use [ruby 2.1.5 (x64)](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

Secondary, if you get an error such as `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 ...` when you run `gem install ruby-oci8` (**without** `--source http://rubygems.org`), fix the SSL error (https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) and run `gem install ruby-oci8` again.

Answer (score 0):

Exception message : "You have to install development tools first" You need to install [devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).